# Updating php5 Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

a customer has a webserver Ubuntu with some websites.
They asked me to update to the latest php version.
After the upgrade, I do not I see more than any website.
I updated php5 and apache2.
I can no longer access to phpmyadmin, even locally.
I tried to look for solutions on the Internet, but I have not solved.
Can anyone give me some advice?

Thank you so much

Comment: have u tried phpinfo?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would check if there are any errors logged. You did not say from which php version to which version you upgraded. A bigger upgrade can be really a showstopper if any of the hosted applications are using deprecated functionality. By default on Ubuntu you will find the errors here: /var/log/apache2/error.log .
Also you should check if apache and php works properly with a simple index.php which contains a simple [phpinfo();](http://php.net/phpinfo) call.